# How to refer to an inparaenum subitem within an enumerate item?

Tags: cross-referencing, paralist

How can I typeset just the `b` (a subitem's label) without the `2` (the enclosing item's label) from a `inparaenum` list within a `enumerate` list?

[image]

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage {paralist}
\begin {document}

\noindent
Here is my list:

\begin {enumerate}

  \item First item.

  \item Second item:
      \begin {inparaenum}[(a)]
      \item \label {first}  first subitem,
      \item \label {second} second subitem.
      \end {inparaenum}

\end {enumerate}

\noindent
I want to typeset `b' not `\ref {second}'.

\end {document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your own environment based on `inparaenum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\makeatletter
\def\zinparaenum{%
  \ifnum\@enumdepth>\thr@@
    \@toodeep
  \else
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
  \fi
  \@ifnextchar[{\@enumlabel@{\@zinparaenum@}[}{\@zinparaenum@}}
\def\@zinparaenum@{%
  \usecounter{\@enumctr}%
  \@namedef{p@\@enumctr}{}%
  \def\@itemlabel{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}%
  \let\@item\pl@item
  \def\makelabel##1{##1}%
  \ignorespaces}
\let\endzinparaenum\ignorespacesafterend
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is my list:
\begin{enumerate}

\item First item.

\item Second item:
  \begin{zinparaenum}[(a)]
  \item \label{first}  first subitem,
  \item \label{second} second subitem.
  \end{zinparaenum}

\end{enumerate}
I want to typeset `b' not `\ref{second}'.

\end{document}
```

The references will be just to the local number, without any prefix, independent of the level of nesting.

[image]

If you look into `paralist.sty`, the code above is just the definition of `inparaenum`, where I added a `z` to every occurrence of `inparaenum`, besides the main change which is locally redefining `\p@<counter>`.

Comment: @n.r. Typo! Sorry. I  added a comment

Answer (score 2):

The crossreference format is stored in a macro named `\p@enumi` etc.

`paralist`'s `inparaenum` extends `enumerate` (up to 6 levels) and uses the counters `enumi`,..., `enumvi` then.

For the second level (it's nested in `enumerate` already, the `\p@enumii` format uses `\theenumi`, i.e. the current first level value, which is `2` in the current example.

The solution is to define `\p@enumii` to be empty.

```
\documentclass {article}



\usepackage {paralist}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{}
\makeatother

\begin {document}
\noindent
Here is my list:

\begin {enumerate}
  \item First item.
  \item Second item:
    \begin {inparaenum}[(a)]
    \item \label {first}  first subitem,
    \item \label {second} second subitem.
    \end {inparaenum}
\end {enumerate}



\noindent
I want to typeset `b' not `\ref {second}'.

\end {document}
```

[image]

Apparently, `paralist` does not allow to change the crossreference format otherwise, an alternative could be `enumitem` with its `inline` lists and the `ref` option.

Comment: It seems it's enough to put the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` block inside the `inparaenum` environment, so as keep it local to that particular list, even if `\ref` is without.

Comment: @n.r. Perhaps, yes. I thought it should be a global settlement

Comment: Smart and Perfect solution.  Works for `\item`s without the use of `paralist` package also !