# reference only nested enumerate inside enumerate environment

Tags: enumerate, ref

i have this code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item first
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item \label{nested_label} first nested
            \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
    \ref{nested_label}
\end{document}
```

where `\ref{nested_label}` produces

```
1a
```

is it possible to reference only the nested enumerate so that `\ref{nested_label}`
produces

```
a
```

Comment: The three lines `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{}
\makeatother`
 taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307681/146828) by @user31729 should solve your concern

Comment: That did it. Many thanks!